# PHPMailer headers AddReplyTo

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer, email-headers

At the moment I got this for the reply:

```
   $mail->AddReplyTo('johndoe@outlook.com');
```

However, I'm looking to put instead the email for the contact form:

```
   $mail->AddReplyTo('$email', '$firstname $name');
```

Obviously, I don't have the good syntax here...
Somebody can hep please?

Comment: What about `$mail->AddReplyTo("$firstname $name <$email>");` PS: not tested

Comment: you can't use single quotes around PHP variables and hope that they will be parsed - double quotes will allow them to be parsed and yield their values.

Comment: Thanks Swetank but it's not working.

Comment: The solution is:   $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email']);